# Как оптимизировать код/избавиться от большого кол-ва однотипных условий?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vkontakte-api, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте.

Вызываю метод `users.get` с нужными мне параметрами. В параметре `fields` указываю 10+ полей. Получаю ответ и проверяю, а существует ли такой объект в нём (пользователь может скрыть некоторую информацию о себе, и соответствующего поля в ответе не будет).

Раньше я просто выводил всю информацию с ответа, но потом решил переделать (чтобы не было такого "Country: undefined" / "City: undefined"). И столкнулся с проблемой. Как избавиться от такого кол-ва условий и сделать проще? Смотрел в сторону `switch`, но так и не смог разобраться.

Буду рад любой помощи. Вот участок кода (на деле условий больше, все они однотипные, кроме последнего):

```
if (r.response[0].bdate) {
  $('#uinfo_container').append('<div class="uinfo_row clearfix"><div class="mg_clr rsp_text pull-left">Birthday:</div><div class="label_r">' + r.response[0].bdate + '</div></div>');
}
if (r.response[0].country) {
  $('#uinfo_container').append('<div class="uinfo_row clearfix"><div class="mg_clr rsp_text pull-left">Country: </div><div class="label_r">' + r.response[0].country.title + '</div></div>');
};
if (r.response[0].city) {
  $('#uinfo_container').append('<div class="uinfo_row clearfix"><div class="mg_clr rsp_text pull-left">City: </div><div class="label_r">' + r.response[0].city.title + '</div></div>');
};
if (r.response[0].home_town) {
  $('#uinfo_container').append('<div class="uinfo_row clearfix"><div class="mg_clr rsp_text pull-left">Hometown: </div><div class="label_r">' + r.response[0].home_town + '</div></div>');
};
if (r.response[0].online == 1) {
  $('#online_status').text('Online');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vphnevL4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
var info = {
  bdate:       { text: 'Birthday'   },
  country:     { text: 'Country',   get: function (c) { return c.title } },
  city:        { text: 'City',      get: function (c) { return c.title } },
  home_town:   { text: 'Hometown'   },
}

var keys = Object.keys(info);
var resp = r.response[0];
var html = '';

function encode(text) {
  return text.replace(/[&<"'>]/g, function (ch) {
    return "#" + ch.charCodeAt(0) + ";";
  });
}

for (var q=0; q<keys.length; ++q) {
  if (resp[keys[q]]) {
    var opts = info[keys[q]];
    var val = resp[keys[q]];

    html += '<div class="uinfo_row clearfix"><div class="mg_clr rsp_text pull-left">' + encode(opts.text) + ':</div><div class="label_r">' + encode(opts.get ? opts.get(val) : val) + '</div></div>');
  }
}

$('#uinfo_container').append(html);

if (r.response[0].online == 1) {
  $('#online_status').text('Online');
}
```

Comment: Эм.. За что минус?

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Это именно то, что нужно. Если Вас не затруднит, не могли бы Вы поподробнее описать функцию encode? Не совсем понимаю зачем она нужна.
P.S. О каком минусе идёт речь? Я ничего никому не ставил :)

Comment: @Kapjushon42, обеспечивает вставку текста, а не разметки. Но вообще-то мне было лень её нормально писать...